# How to Detect that call is coming on sim 1 or sim 2

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am working on an app where I need to know if an incoming call is coming on sim 1 or sim 2.  In some devices it's detected by the broadcast receiver, but this detection does not occur on all devices.

How can I detect that a call is coming in on sim 1 or sim 2?

Comment: How much have you done? Any progress?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar yes,  receiver i am getting intent and in this intent i got subscription (0,1) on this basics i detect that incoming call is for sim 1 or sim 2, its working fine in moto e 4.4 and one of lg device but in samsung device its not working in samsung device i only get subscription 0, only one value, if call is coming for sim 2 or sim 1 it only gives subscription 0